# duplicate meta tag

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags

I have a simple xml plus xslt that when opened in IE9 gets a meta tag added.
The xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<root/>
```

And the xslt adds a meta tag as follows

```
  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      ...
```

Now when I open the file in IE9, developer tools show that it opens in IE9 standards mode all right, but that it has two meta tags. Apparently IE9 adds one in the process of loading and applying the xslt.

[image: duplicate meta tag]

I wonder two things:
(1) can this affect the way the file is displayed in IE9 (or in earlier IE versions)?
(2) why does IE9 add the second meta tag and can it be avoided?

Comment: AFAIK, IE9 adds meta-tag to facilitate display of XML doc inside browser/DOM. So it is transient tag and should not affect original XML in anyway...

Comment: I know it does not affect the original XML. Maybe you thought I meant that by "harmful" but I meant whether it could influence the displayed information on IE9. I changed (1) above accordingly in order to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this further and found the answers I was looking for.

`meta` `http-equiv` intends to set an http header field. Because Content-type and X-UA-Compatible are different http header fields, they don't interfere with each other (an interesting question would be what happens if the xslt would add a Content-type meta tag, and IE9 adds another one).

IE9 apparently adds the meta tag to the html header when converting the byte order mark received when downloading the xml file; the BOM is a utf-16 one and thus overrides the utf-8 one in the xml header (hence the HTML1114 message).
Can this be avoided? I guess not.